# Reading JSON from Url java

Tags: java, json, gson, wunderground

I am having trouble with parson the JSON from a URL. Below, is the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Test_Application {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = readUrl("http://api.wunderground.com/api/57dd9039b81a9c21/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json");

        Page page = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);

        System.out.println(page.description);
        System.out.println(page.language);
        System.out.println(page.link);
        System.out.println(page.title);

    }

    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }

    }

    static class Page {
        String title;
        String link;
        String description;
        String language;
        List<Item> items;
    }

    static class Item {
        String title;
        String link;
        String description;
    }


}
```

The output is:

```
null
null
null
null
```

What I think the problem is that, I have an inappropriate class to read the data. Would that be correct?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The website returns the following:

```
{
  "response": {
    "version": "0.1",
    "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
    "features": {
      "conditions": 1
    }
  },
  "current_observation": {
    "image": {
      "url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
      "title": "Weather Underground",
      "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
    },
    "display_location": {
      "full": "San Francisco, CA",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "state": "CA",
      "state_name": "California",
      "country": "US",
      "country_iso3166": "US",
      "zip": "94101",
      "latitude": "37.77500916",
      "longitude": "-122.41825867",
      "elevation": "47.00000000"
    },
    "observation_location": {
      "full": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California",
      "city": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco",
      "state": "California",
      "country": "US",
      "country_iso3166": "US",
      "latitude": "37.773285",
      "longitude": "-122.417725",
      "elevation": "49 ft"
    },
    "estimated": {

    },
    "station_id": "KCASANFR58",
    "observation_time": "Last Updated on February 19, 7:08 AM PST",
    "observation_time_rfc822": "Tue, 19 Feb 2013 07:08:18 -0800",
    "observation_epoch": "1361286498",
    "local_time_rfc822": "Tue, 19 Feb 2013 07:08:31 -0800",
    "local_epoch": "1361286511",
    "local_tz_short": "PST",
    "local_tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "local_tz_offset": "-0800",
    "weather": "Mostly Cloudy",
    "temperature_string": "47.9 F (8.8 C)",
    "temp_f": 47.9,
    "temp_c": 8.8,
    "relative_humidity": "87%",
    "wind_string": "From the SW at 4.0 MPH Gusting to 13.0 MPH",
    "wind_dir": "SW",
    "wind_degrees": 225,
    "wind_mph": 4.0,
    "wind_gust_mph": "13.0",
    "wind_kph": 6.4,
    "wind_gust_kph": "20.9",
    "pressure_mb": "1012",
    "pressure_in": "29.90",
    "pressure_trend": "-",
    "dewpoint_string": "44 F (7 C)",
    "dewpoint_f": 44,
    "dewpoint_c": 7,
    "heat_index_string": "NA",
    "heat_index_f": "NA",
    "heat_index_c": "NA",
    "windchill_string": "46 F (8 C)",
    "windchill_f": "46",
    "windchill_c": "8",
    "feelslike_string": "46 F (8 C)",
    "feelslike_f": "46",
    "feelslike_c": "8",
    "visibility_mi": "10.0",
    "visibility_km": "16.1",
    "solarradiation": "",
    "UV": "0",
    "precip_1hr_string": "0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
    "precip_1hr_in": "0.00",
    "precip_1hr_metric": " 0",
    "precip_today_string": "0.02 in (1 mm)",
    "precip_today_in": "0.02",
    "precip_today_metric": "1",
    "icon": "mostlycloudy",
    "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/mostlycloudy.gif",
    "forecast_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html",
    "history_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KCASANFR58",
    "ob_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=37.773285,-122.417725"
  }
}
```

**Updated code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Test_Application {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = readUrl("http://api.wunderground.com/api/57dd9039b81a9c21/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json");

        // Page page = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);
        Response response = gson.fromJson(json, Response.class);

        System.out.println(response.termsOfService);
        System.out.println(response.version);

    }

    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }

    }

    static class Response{
        String version;
        String termsOfService;
    }


}
```

Comment: @downvoter, may I please have the reason to improve the post?

Comment: What does the website return?

Comment: P.S. I didn't downvote.

Comment: The problem is that your POJO doen't resemble the JSON in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @bmorris591 Thanks :) I have updated the code with the response. I have used an online JSON viewer to get the response.

Comment: @BrianRoach is correct, you need to create a POJO that matches the JSON.

Comment: @BrianRoach could you please provide a simple example? I'm having trouble with the POJO concept.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826237/reading-a-json-reply-from-weatherunderground/14842859#14842859 In fact, this could probably be closed as a dup.

Comment: @gekkostate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826237/reading-a-json-reply-from-weatherunderground) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910124/how-to-meaningfully-extract-information-from-a-json-reply/14910200#14910200) may be helpful.

Comment: @BrianRoach In essence, I have to go through the various aspects of the JSON and make a relevant POJO that can deserialize?

Comment: That is correct. JSON represents an object. Your Java object (POJO) needs to match that object. Or as I show in the answer I link to, you can just parse it and pick out the items you want and not use a POJO.

Comment: THe *one* exception being that you don't have to create the *entire* object in Java if you only want certain parts of the JSON. Gson will silently ignore any part of the JSON that you don't include in your POJO (And vice versa, as you have discovered - that's why all your fields are currently null).

Comment: @BrianRoach Great! It would be great, if you would like to add this as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives to GSON exists:

- [Convert Json to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map)
- http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=45.

This snippet may help to do a **generic** decoder:

```
Map< String, Object > decoded =
   gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken< Map< String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

The following code is a beginning of a **specific** decoder:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test_Application
{
   public static void main(
      String[] args ) throws Exception
   {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = readUrl(
         "http://api.wunderground.com/api/57dd9039b81a9c21/" +
         "conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json" );
      System.out.println( json );

      Map< String, Object > decoded =
         gson.fromJson(
            json,
            new TypeToken< Map< String, Object>>() {}.getType());
      System.out.println( decoded );

      Answer answer = gson.fromJson( json, Answer.class );
      System.out.println( answer.response.version );
      System.out.println( answer.response.termsofService );
      System.out.println( answer.response.features.get( "conditions" ));
      System.out.println( answer.current_observation.image );
      System.out.println( answer.current_observation.display_location );
   }

   static class Response
   {
      String                version;
      URL                   termsofService;
      Map< String, String > features;
   }

   static class Observation
   {
      Map< String, String > image;
      Map< String, String > display_location;
      // TODO: complete me
   }

   static class Location
   {
      // TODO: complete me
   }

   static class Answer
   {
      Response    response;
      Observation current_observation;
      Location    display_location;
      // TODO: complete me
   }
```

At this state of development, it returns:

```
{response={version=0.1, termsofService=http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html, features={conditions=1.0}}, current_observation={image={url=http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png, title=Weather Underground, link=http://www.wunderground.com}, display_location={full=San Francisco, CA, city=San Francisco, state=CA, state_name=California, country=US, country_iso3166=US, zip=94101, latitude=37.77500916, longitude=-122.41825867, elevation=47.00000000}, observation_location={full=SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California, city=SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, state=California, country=US, country_iso3166=US, latitude=37.773285, longitude=-122.417725, elevation=49 ft}, estimated={}, station_id=KCASANFR58, observation_time=Last Updated on February 19, 8:16 AM PST, observation_time_rfc822=Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:16:18 -0800, observation_epoch=1361290578, local_time_rfc822=Tue, 19 Feb 2013 08:16:18 -0800, local_epoch=1361290578, local_tz_short=PST, local_tz_long=America/Los_Angeles, local_tz_offset=-0800, weather=Mostly Cloudy, temperature_string=48.7 F (9.3 C), temp_f=48.7, temp_c=9.3, relative_humidity=83%, wind_string=From the ESE at 1.0 MPH, wind_dir=ESE, wind_degrees=109.0, wind_mph=1.0, wind_gust_mph=0.0, wind_kph=1.6, wind_gust_kph=0.0, pressure_mb=1012, pressure_in=29.88, pressure_trend=-, dewpoint_string=44 F (7 C), dewpoint_f=44.0, dewpoint_c=7.0, heat_index_string=NA, heat_index_f=NA, heat_index_c=NA, windchill_string=49 F (9 C), windchill_f=49, windchill_c=9, feelslike_string=49 F (9 C), feelslike_f=49, feelslike_c=9, visibility_mi=10.0, visibility_km=16.1, solarradiation=, UV=0, precip_1hr_string=0.00 in ( 0 mm), precip_1hr_in=0.00, precip_1hr_metric= 0, precip_today_string=0.02 in (1 mm), precip_today_in=0.02, precip_today_metric=1, icon=mostlycloudy, icon_url=http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/mostlycloudy.gif, forecast_url=http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html, history_url=http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KCASANFR58, ob_url=http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=37.773285,-122.417725}}

0.1
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html
1
{url=http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png, title=Weather Underground, link=http://www.wunderground.com}
{full=San Francisco, CA, city=San Francisco, state=CA, state_name=California, country=US, country_iso3166=US, zip=94101, latitude=37.77500916, longitude=-122.41825867, elevation=47.00000000}
```

Comment: once I fill in the classes you have specified, I should be able to access the data right?

Comment: Just as an FYI (And I only know this from other WU JSON questions) `features` in `Response` can actually contain a bunch of things which is why in my `Response` it's a `Map`. I don't know the full list of possibilities; you could also flesh out a complete `Features` object if there's a list in the API docs of all of them.

Comment: Yes, but it's painful, if you want just use fields, a generic Map< String, Object > with a custom made parser may be useful.

Comment: THere is literally no reason to do what you state given the Gson will happily act as a generic JSON parser if you don't want to use a POJO. It's in my original answer that this question is really a dup of ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your POJO doesn't match your JSON.

JSON represents an object, and your POJO needs to match it. Here's a start of what that would look like (all fields public with no getters/setters just to make this example small):

```
class MyWUPojo {
    public Response response;
    // more after this that match the JSON
}

class Response {
    public String version;
    public String termsofservice;
    public Map<String, Integer> features;
}
```

Note that the one caveat is that if you are only interested in *part* of the JSON response, that's all you have to implement. Gson will silently ignore any part of the JSON you haven't included in your POJO.